# Gathering data from inconsistant HTML pages - JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get a lot of data from multiple pages but its not always consistent. here is an example of the html I am working with!:

[Example HTML](http://infohound.net/tidy/tidy.pl?_function=download&file=t27719_183034.html.tdy&_display=inline)

I need to get something like: Team | Team | Result all into different variables or lists.

I just need some help on where to start because the main table I'm working with on multiple pages isn't the same on everyone.

heres my java so far:

```
    try {
        Document team_page = Jsoup.connect("http://www.soccerstats.com/team.asp?league=" + league + "&teamid=" + teamNumber).get();
        Element home_team = team_page.select("[class=homeTitle]").first();
        String teamName = home_team.text();
        System.out.println(teamName + "'s Latest Results: ");

        Elements main_page = team_page.select("[class=stat]");
        System.out.println(main_page);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse content");
    }
```

I am getting the league and teamid from different methods of my program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is one of the problems with webpage scraping.

You have to *figure out* one or more heuristics that will extract the information that you need across all of the pages that you need to access.  There's no magic bullet.  Just hard work.  (And you'll have to do it all over again if the site changes its page layout.)

---

A better idea is to request the information as XML or JSON using the site or sites' RESTful APIs ... assuming they exist and are available to you.

(And if you continue with the web-scraping approach, check the site's Terms of Service to make sure that your activity is acceptable.)

Comment: update on the HTML, this is all I need to extract from: http://infohound.net/tidy/tidy.pl?_function=download&file=t28455_844200.html.tdy&_display=inline